# How to add strings inside array?

Tags: php

I have this array:

```
$address = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_address_formatted_address', array(
                'first_name'  => get_user_meta( $customer_id, $name . '_first_name', true ),
                'last_name'   => get_user_meta( $customer_id, $name . '_last_name', true ),
                'country'     => get_user_meta( $customer_id, $name . '_country', true )

            ), $customer_id, $name );
```

**the output is:**

John

Silver

USA

**I want to make it:**

First name: John

Second Name: Silver

Country: USA

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php

Comment: 'first_name'  => "First name: ".get_user_meta( $customer_id, $name . '_first_name', true ),

Comment: thanks for help! At list you have tried!